# Cross Browser navigation CSS

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am trying to build a simple CSS only navigation bar for my site. This is it working fine in modern browsers:

[image: Nav in modern Browser]

And this is my CSS:

```
#nav{
    width:496px;
    height:45px;
    float:right;
    background-color:#bee199;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
    margin-top:5px;
    border:1px solid #a09f9f;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
    #nav ul{
        list-style:none;
        text-align:center;
    }
    #nav ul .last{
        padding-right:0px;
        border-right:none;
    }
    #nav ul li.navsep{
        width:1px;
        height:44px;
        background-color:#a09f9f;
        padding:0;
        margin-right:10px;
    }
        #nav ul li{
            width:auto;
            height:44px;
            display: -moz-inline-stack;
            display:inline-block;
            padding-right:10px;
            margin-bottom:-16px;
        }
            #nav ul li a{
                font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size:20px;
                font-weight:400;
                text-decoration:none;
                color:#434342;
            }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="principles.html" title="principles">Principles</a></li>
                <li class="navsep"><span></span></li>
                <li><a href="#edit" title="Our Services">Our services</a></li>
                <li class="navsep"><span></span></li>
                <li><a href="recent.html" title="Recent work">Recent work</a></li>
                <li class="navsep"><span></span></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="#edit" title="Contact Us">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

One of my problems is using negative margins, I really don't want to be using them. But every time I try to use conventional methods the text will not center vertically and it looks like this:

This also happens on older browsers.

Thanks for your time! If you need more information just ask! :)

[image: Broken Nav]

Comment: specifically, *which* older browsers are you having problems with? Have you got a valid doctype on your page?

Comment: I was testing this in FF 2, it also happens in IE 5,6,7

Comment: wow. what on earth makes you want to support all of those??! you've probably spent more time testing for each of those browsers than anyone will *ever* spend visiting your site in any of them. In a few cases where you know your audience it's possible to justify supporting IE7 and maybe IE6, but FF2 and IE5? hehehehe. Please don't support them; it's not worth your time.

Comment: I'm not really worried about FF2. My main problem is getting IE 6+ working. When I did C.B. testing I ran into the same problem with lots of older browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Omit the `<li class="navsep">` and use borders instead.
2. use lineheight on the `li` elements.

Comment: When I did that the links move to the top of the nav div. And line height is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using negative margin use line-height, in your case `#nav ul li {height: 44px; line-height: 44px;}` this will vertical center your text

Comment: When I do that it ends up like this http://tinypic.com/r/24uxnyg/6 But the only thing I did was remove the negative margin and add line-height. Was there other things I need to do?

Comment: I don't really know what is happening as long as I can not know if there are any other elements that interfere with your menu. I'll suggest to give a smaller line-height, get rid of that separator `<li>`, use borders instead, and `float:left` your list items

Comment: You can view all of the source here: www.rslynch.com/v3/ Hope that helps. I will try your suggestions and comment if it works

Comment: For IE7 you need to use `display:inline` instead of `inline-block`. It's better to have a separate css for older versions of IE. And as I said you need to set `float:left` to your list items